# WCF error parameter date equals "01/01/0001"

Tags: wcf

I am currently sending from SoapUI for my tests the following request:

```
<caja:GenerarObligacion>
  <caja:Obligacion>
    <obl:BenCheq>TALLERES ARROYO</obl:BenCheq>
    <obl:CodMoneda>S/.</obl:CodMoneda>
    <obl:CodProd>VM14</obl:CodProd>
    <obl:CodRamo>AUTO</obl:CodRamo>
    <obl:CodUsuario>ACSELP</obl:CodUsuario>
    <obl:DptoEmi>000101</obl:DptoEmi>
    <obl:FecFinVig>2024-02-28T12:00:01</obl:FecFinVig>
    <obl:FecIniVig>2025-02-28T12:00:01</obl:FecIniVig>
    <obl:FecMod>2026-07-17T13:02:05</obl:FecMod>
    <obl:FecNotif>2026-07-17T13:02:05</obl:FecNotif>
    <obl:FecOcurr>2025-01-28T08:41:53</obl:FecOcurr>
    <obl:FecRecepDocPago>2025-01-28T00:00:00</obl:FecRecepDocPago>
    <obl:IdePol>25000293961</obl:IdePol>
    <obl:IdeSin>1500013900</obl:IdeSin>
    <obl:IndCheque>S</obl:IndCheque>
    <obl:ItemOblig>
      <fac:BEDetalleObligacion>
        <fac:CodCpto>DSCTOS</fac:CodCpto>
        <fac:ItemDoc/>
        <fac:FecFact>2025-01-28T00:00:00</fac:FecFact>
        <fac:MtoCptoEgre>600.0</fac:MtoCptoEgre>
        <fac:NroFact>444444444</fac:NroFact>
        <fac:NumCpto>1</fac:NumCpto>
        <fac:SerieFact>f045</fac:SerieFact>
        <fac:TipoRegCompra>01</fac:TipoRegCompra>
      </fac:BEDetalleObligacion>
      <fac:BEDetalleObligacion>
        <fac:CodCpto>ISLV</fac:CodCpto>
        <fac:ItemDoc/>
        <fac:FecFact>2025-01-28T00:00:00</fac:FecFact>
        <fac:MtoCptoEgre>108.0</fac:MtoCptoEgre>
        <fac:NroFact>444444444</fac:NroFact>
        <fac:NumCpto>2</fac:NumCpto>
        <fac:SerieFact>f045</fac:SerieFact>
        <fac:TipoRegCompra>01</fac:TipoRegCompra>
      </fac:BEDetalleObligacion>
    </obl:ItemOblig>
    <obl:MtoAprob>708.0</obl:MtoAprob>
    <obl:NumAprob>18000493</obl:NumAprob>
    <obl:NumPol>2500029396</obl:NumPol>
    <obl:StsOblig>VAL</obl:StsOblig>
    <obl:StsSin>ACT</obl:StsSin>
    <obl:TasaCambio>1.0</obl:TasaCambio>
    <obl:TipoAprob>P</obl:TipoAprob>
    <obl:TipoBenef>TALR</obl:TipoBenef>
    <obl:TipoDocPago>CHQ</obl:TipoDocPago>
  </caja:Obligacion>
  <caja:Tercero>
    <ter:BETercero>
      <ter:NumId>650606871</ter:NumId>
      <ter:TipoId>J</ter:TipoId>
    </ter:BETercero>
  </caja:Tercero>
</caja:GenerarObligacion>
```

All the data arrives well except for the "FecFact" field, as seen in the request this field if it has a date but when arriving at the visual debug the following value "01/01/0001" is displayed:

[image: image1]

In spite of sending a value to the FecFact field, it is set with the date that is displayed in the image "01/01/0001" as if the field were arriving null. This is the declaration of my entity.

```
[DataMember]
public String CodCtpo { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public DateTime FecFact { get; set; }
[DataMember]  //IndIGV
public String IndnoGravado { get; set; }
[DataMember] //MtoCptoAprob
public Decimal MtoCptoEgre { get; set; }
[DataMember] // NumCpto - ?uso?   NUMDETOBLIG
public Int32 NumCpto { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public String NroFact { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public String SerieFact { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public String TipoRegCompra { get; set; } //Funcional como OB
[DataMember]
public String CodSvcio { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code - not everyone will be able to see them.  Copy and paste the code from your editor.  Having said that, I'm not sure there's enough information here to make an educated guess as to what's gong on.   Something is happening that leads WCF to use the default value for `DateTime`, but without more code (the full DataContract class and the code from the service that is receiving the request) it will be hard to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` is initialized by default by `DateTime.MinValue`, which is actually `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` exactly same as what you are getting.

You should declare nullable field if want null Date like:

```
DateTime? dt = null;
```

**OR**

Compare `DateTime` variables to DateTime.MinValue & set corresponding value in database query as null or in UI variable as null.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I have restored your problem successfully,
The only thing you need to do is try to assign the NameSpace attribute to the DataContract Class.

```
    [DataContract(Namespace ="mydomain")]
    public class Product
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
     }
```

I hope this information is useful.